# How to have default behaviour on a derived class instead of redefining constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, code-reuse, repeat

I noticed that I'm reusing a lot of code in my inheritance hierarchy, and I was wondering if there isn't a better way. I have an Item class from which many other types of item can inherit:

```
struct Item{ 
    Item(){};
    Item(string name) : name(name){}
    string name;
};
```

So this is a class that can be created with no name (the default), or a name provided. All is good. But say I have a class inheriting from Item:

```
struct Book : Item
{
};
```

I can't then do:

```
Book harryPotter("Harry Potter");
```

If I want the same type of behaviour, where I can choose to provide a string or not, I have to do the following:

```
struct Book : Item
{
    Book(string name) : Item(name) {}   // Set the name in base's initialiser list
    // Or...
    Book(string name) { this->name = name; }  // Set the name in derived's constructor
};
```

In both cases I then have to write a separate default constructor, as the compiler won't provide one where I've made my own type.

Then, as far as I can see, this will have to be retyped each time I create a new Item type.

And I've realised this problem happens even if I don't want a default constructor, if I want to create a type of Item, I have to explicitly create the constructor for each one?

Edit: Thanks to Sam Varshavchik for this, starting from C++11 you can inherit constructors with:

```
using Base::Base;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
struct Book : Item
{
    using Item::Item;
};
```

This is going to, essentially, inherit all of `Item`'s constructors into `Book`.

Comment: Wow, is this syntax a special exception yet again for inheriting constructors? Because I can't make sense of just the line using Item::Item; I think the second Item is the default constructor of base. This is good news, but confusing. I'm going to search for this.

Comment: Wow, this is specifically a C++11 and later feature. I can't get over how much this language is changing recently. Is there like a renaissance in C++ or something?

Comment: C++ has changed dramatically in the last seven years. It's about three-four times as big, in terms functionality and complexity, as it was seven years ago. It is simultaneously more complex, but also the new complexity actually makes many things easier than they were before. Like this, for example.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice Yes, it is an idiom, which is to say, you cannot make sense of it from general principles. It puzzled me too the first time I saw it. It is in C++11 and later. Very convenient.